# Comparing value of an object with null

Tags: java, null, equals

The `null` literal can only be assigned to reference variables, and usually, we use the `.equals()` method in comparing with them

Why do we use the operators "equal to" and "not equal to" instead of the `.equals()` method if dealing with null?

Comment: Because if `x` is null, then `x.equals(y)` will throw an exception.

Comment: Because if that reference is null, then it would throw NullPointerException and that is the reason you need to check it with "==" or "!="

Comment: can you try `Objects.equals(o1, o2)`?

Comment: `Objects.equals(x, y)` is a helper method which first checks for null and then calls `equals` on the object.

Answer (score 3):

`equals` is a method, meaning you cannot call it on a `null` reference (although you could call `myVariable.equals(aVariableThatIsNull)`, and it should return `false`).

You could use [`java.util.Objects#equals(Object, Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) to clean up your code, and seemless handle null-safe equality checks.

Answer (score 1):

There are three reasons in the following order of importance:

1. **Stability** - The fear of `NullPointerException` which would most certainly happen if you tried to access `equals()` method from a object that holds a `null` value. This is pretty obvious but still had to be mentioned as the primary reason.
2. **Visibility** - However even if we could do that and it wouldn't throw an exception it would still **not** be more preferable to using the `==` operator. Why? Because the operator visually separates the elements making it more clear what is actually being compared. When we are comparing to a `null` we want it to be clear and visible within the code.
3. **Consistency** - Equals method is used for **content comparison** while the `==` operator is used for **address comparison**. Since null has no address because it doesn't exist the most logically consistent thing would be to first compare the lack of address before moving on to compare the actual content of two objects (which is what `equals()` does).

Answer (score 0):

Method "equals()" is an instance method, and to call any instance method , you need a non null object reference. So calling equals() with null reference will result in NPE.

If the method is static, then you can invoke that method with null reference too as static method is not bound to any instance.